# Creating an API for Android, iOS and Web

Tags: android, ios, api

So I am creating a project with a couple of buddies and I need to create an API. This is my first time creating a big project and creating my own API. I don't know where to start. The project that we're working on will have a website, an app for Android and IOS, and use PostgreSQL. We will be using Javascript and Node.js as well. If there are any tips about creating API's for Android, IOS, and Web please let me know.

Comment: how did this question get an upvote? This is like the definition of too broad.

Comment: It's unclear if you are asking an infrastructure question or a software design question. And exactly what subject you want advise on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you read ["RESTful Web Services"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260) by Richardson

The book gives a thorough grounding in the "why?" behind organizing resources restfully.  Also provides a good outline of different RESTful authentication mechanisms and the pros and cons of each - vital for a mobile app talking to a web-based back-end.

Then, sit back and outline the resources that will be necessary to run your app and have at it!

Answer (score 0):

First of all take paper and  pen to start design the architecture and write down all use cases. Also define the way data will be access.
While creating an API for mobile apps we should keep some important things in mind. First what type of API it should be JSON based or XML. And I will prefer JSON for mobile app as its lightweight and will take less time to parse. Also it will be fast to transmit. While XML bit costly.
One of most important thing you should design the api as secure as it could be. Because sensitive information can be sniff by some one. better to use SSL hand shake to make it secure.